# VS Code scroll up/down moving the cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, scroll

When scrolling down in VSCode. Using arrow keys makes you have the cursor on the bottom. I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> This scrolls the screen and the cursor keeps its position. In this case I need to click on the new line in order to start editing. However I'm looking for a way to scroll and move the cursor. For example if I'm in the middle of the screen I want to scroll and get the cursor to maintain its relative position in the middle.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: I'm here for the witness statement that this may be the single most frustrating thing in VSCode, for years. You must either reach out for the mouse (in a coder's editor!) for this one workaround click only, or you have to scroll _twice_ to actually reach the position, where your eye already is... Not only that, the screen will then typically also jump a page, shattering the visual context that needs to be rebuilt cognitively then, too... BTW, did you notice they can't handle simple PgUp/PgDn optimally either? :-o (Reminds me of the times where MS used to be industry leader in UI ergonomics.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of the extension [Multi Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

Add this setting

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.up1LineKeepCursor",
      "sequence": [
        {"command": "editorScroll", "args": {"to": "up", "by": "line" }},
        "cursorUp"
      ]
    },
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.down1LineKeepCursor",
      "sequence": [
        {"command": "editorScroll", "args": {"to": "down", "by": "line" }},
        "cursorDown"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And these keybindings

```
  {
    "key": "shift+ctrl+alt+up",
    "command": "multiCommand.up1LineKeepCursor",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+ctrl+alt+down",
    "command": "multiCommand.down1LineKeepCursor",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

You can use any key binding you like.

It works good when `Word Wrap` is OFF.

Comment: Thanks! Just to reiterate: so, you need to _install an extension_, plus add a _custom config snippet_ (well, two...) for this basic action that virtually every single code editor on the planet can just do by default, including those that have code editing only as a side-job, like FAR Manager's or Midnight Commander's built-in editors. ;)

Comment: @Sz. you can move the setting to the key binding (see the Multi Command page). VSC can't do everything everybody wants out of the box. VSC is programmable so you can do anything you want. VSC is an extension engine. If does not do it out of the box install/write an extension.

Comment: I think `{ "command": "cursorMove", "args": { "to": "viewPortIfOutside" } }` as the second command would work more reliably.

Comment: @rioV8, thanks for the hint, I'll look into it. (As to "VSC is programmable so you can do anything you want", well, that's obvious, and unrelated to my point ("...basic action that virtually every single code editor on the planet can just do by default"). I mean, it's semantically equivalent to saying that "computers are programmable, so you can do anything you want, incl. coding your own editor".

Comment: @Sz. I'm used to working with editors that are fixed. You where not able to modify or add any functionality. Emacs was different but tricky to program (Lisp as scripting language). And this is completely different from writing your own editor. What certain code editors implement by default is different. It is a question like I want editorX to behave just like editorY. Then just use editorY.

Comment: @rioV8, I meant "obvious" for VSCode (as that's the context). And I'm used to customizable editors like even Multi-Edit _for DOS_, which was completely & delightfully hackable (sg. I made use of to the extreme), already in the early 90s. I mean, for coding, that's the norm. OTOH, this "pan" feature in the OP was built-in there, too (bound to Ctrl+Up/Dn). I have yet to come across a decent _code_ editor that wouldn't offer it without jumping through hoops. Apart from VSCode, that is. (Hence, my frustration. It has various other similar basic, and weird, "regressions" for no good reason.)

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible with these commands:

```json
    {
        "key": "cmd+down",
        "command": "editorScroll",
        "when": "textInputFocus",
        "args": {
            "to": "down",
            "by": "line",
            "revealCursor": true,
            "value": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+up",
        "command": "editorScroll",
        "when": "textInputFocus",
        "args": {
            "to": "up",
            "by": "line",
            "revealCursor": true,
            "value": 1
        }
    }
```